# C# need help for method access?

Tags: c#, function, return

I'm having following program for reading test file

```
public static string[] method1()
{
    //List<string[]> allLines = new List<string[]>();
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader("data.txt");
    // write a line of text to the file
    string word = tr.ReadLine();

    //now split this line into words
    string[] val = word.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

    //Console.WriteLine(val[0]);
    //Console.WriteLine(val[1]);
    //Console.ReadLine();
    return val;
}

public static void method2()
{
   method1();
   var value1= val[0];
  //Console.WriteLine(val[0]);
}
```

It s shows Error the name 'val' does not exist in the current context. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the return value from the method to your `var`

```
var val = method1();
```

Then you can do :

```
if(val.Length > 0)
     var value1= val[0];
```

Also you can improve your method like:

```
public static string[] method1()
    {

       //...Textreader lines and then 
        return word.Split(','); // no need to use new Char[] as , is already a single character
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign variable val correctly see below how to use it correctly

```
public static void method2()
{
       var val = method1();
        var value1= val[0];
      Console.WriteLine(value1);
```

> I would suggest you check if val.Length is > 0 before using it with
>   [0]
>
> But if you confident that Length of string[] returned from method1
>   will always have [0] index and you just want to use the
>   [0] from it than why not use a much shorter syntax

**Like this:**

```
Console.WriteLine(method1()[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not defined val in method2. Try:

public static void method2()

```
{ 
 var val =  method1(); 
    var value1= val[0]; 
  //Console.WriteLine(val[0]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the result returned from the method 1:

```
 public static string[] method1()
    {
        //List<string[]> allLines = new List<string[]>();
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("data.txt");
        // write a line of text to the file
        string word = tr.ReadLine();

        //now split this line into words
        string[] val = word.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

        //Console.WriteLine(val[0]);
        //Console.WriteLine(val[1]);
        //Console.ReadLine();
        return val;
    }

    public static void method2()
    {

        var value1 = method1();

        Console.WriteLine(value1.First());
        //Console.WriteLine(val[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of `method2`, `method1` is:

```
public static string[] method1()
```

That's it. All the other code in method1 is unknown to it. It doesn't know about `tr`, or `word` or `val`. It won't know if you change them (which is one of the several reasons why this ignorance on `method2`'s part is a good thing). The only thing `method2` "knows" is that `method1` is static, takes zero parameters, and returns an array of strings.

Hence you need to do something with the return. You can store it in a variable, which could be called `val` or something else.

```
public static void method2()
{
   var val = method1();
   var value1= val[0];
   Console.WriteLine(val[0]);
}
```

Or equally:

```
public static void method2()
{
   var imBoredOfTheNameVal = method1();
   var value1= imBoredOfTheNameVal[0];
   Console.WriteLine(imBoredOfTheNameVal[0]);
}
```

The two are exactly the same.

You can also act on a returned value directly:

```
public static void method2()
{
   Console.WriteLine(method1()[0]);
}
```